# Do you lose generality every time you introduce $ \tan{\alpha} $ in a trigonometric identity?

Tags: trigonometry, logic, solution-verification

So I stumbled upon this question when I got exposed to trigonometric identities such as
$$ \sin{\alpha} = \frac{2 \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1 + \tan^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}, $$
and
$$ \cos{\alpha} = \frac{1 - \tan^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1 + \tan^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}. $$

In the proofs of the above identities we have to make, what I believe to be, an assumption that makes the above $ \sin{\alpha} $ and $ \cos{\alpha} $ non-equivalent to the *actual* definitions of sine and cosine. Thinking about this has really challenged the logic and reasoning side of my mathematical knowledge. To make my title question more concrete I'll illustrate with a proof.

We have
$$ \sin{\alpha} = \frac{\sin{ \left( 2 \cdot \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) }}{1} = \frac{2 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}, $$
and all is fine since we're still defined for all $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, $ hence
$$ \sin{\alpha} \equiv \frac{2 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}. $$
But then to rewrite it in terms of tangent, we have to multiply the RHS by 1 and thus,
\begin{align}
\sin{\alpha} = \frac{2 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} \Leftarrow \sin{\alpha} &= \frac{ 2 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}  \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}}{ \left( \cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}} \\
&= \frac{2 \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1 + \tan^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}
\end{align}

instead of

\begin{align}
\sin{\alpha} = \frac{2 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} \Leftrightarrow \sin{\alpha} &= \frac{ 2 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}}{ \left( \cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \right) \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}} \\
&= \frac{2 \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1 + \tan^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}
\end{align}

since there would be values $\alpha$ that would cause the right side to be false and thus we would have lost some generality and it feels more fair to say that

$$ \sin{\alpha} \not\equiv \frac{2 \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1 + \tan^{2}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}} $$
because it's not really true *for all* values so you can't just blindly "plug it in" without some thought.

To drive home the question, does this argument, assuming it's true, hold for every trigonometric identity where you have to introduce tangent and cotangent? Does this also apply to general equations, not just trigonometry? What really *is* an identity if not something true for all values?

Comment: In one of the steps you are multiplying by $\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}}$, that could be not well defined

Comment: Multiplying by $1$ is not a problem. The problem is when "$1$" is written in the form $(1/cos^2(\alpha/2))/(1/cos^2(\alpha/2))$, which is not defined when $\alpha$ is an odd multiple of $\pi.$ Those values of $\alpha$ are also precisely the ones for which $\tan(\alpha/2)$ is not defined, so these "gaps" in the identity should be obvious at first glance.

Comment: So the short answer to the question is that whenever an identity includes a function of $\alpha$ that is undefined for some real numbers $\alpha,$ the identity is not valid for those values of $\alpha.$ There's an implicit condition, "whenever all terms in this equation are defined." Sometimes people write the condition explicitly in some form.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the $\tan$ function has discontinuities, whilst the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions don't, and there are values for which the alternative formula is not defined. The missing values can be recovered by continuity. The same applies to other formulae of a similar kind where zeros and infinities and discontinuities come in.

---

The formulae are related to the fact that $$(x,y)=\left(\frac {1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac {2t}{1+t^2}\right)$$ is a parametrisation of the unit circle with the point $(1,0)$ corresponding to $t=0$. If you draw a line from the point $A=(-1,0)$ to another point $P$ on the circle, with the origin being $O$ then:

If the angle between $OP$ and the $x-$axis is $\alpha$ then the angle between $AP$ and the $x-$axis is $\frac {\alpha}{2}$ and the parameter $t$ corresponding to the point is $t=\tan \frac {\alpha}{2}$.

If you explore this with a diagram you will see what happens as the point $P$ approaches $A$.

The formula becomes useful for applications like integration (where trigonometric functions can be transformed into rational functions). The method is one of the beginnings of algebraic geometry.

In the context of integration, removable singularities tend not to be a problem (though care is always necessary). In algebraic geometry, singularities can be a feature of the point of view, and there are methods for dealing with/analysing those commonly encountered. When you look at a circle as a circle, it is clearly continuous and joined up. When you see it through the $t$ parametrisation, it can seem as though there could be a gap.

I have put this last bit to suggest that your question is a good one, but the eventual mathematical resolution of the question need not be the thing that first comes to mind.

Comment: Very insightful.